# How to get the event invoking div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a couple of divs that when clicked opens a fancybox with a textfield that takes a message and then saves the form. This does not work when I want to reuse it, ie using the same function and code for multiple forms. It always pretends to the be first button. And for every time I use it the number of time it runs the callback function increases. Does anyone know what I did wrong? I tried adding the each(), but it did not help.

I'm sorry for the brief explanation, it is a lot clearer when looking at the code (note: I use console.log for the output): http://jsfiddle.net/EvYvc/11/

Basically: I wan't to know what element invoked the click function and get it's attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of changes,

1. You need to bind the click handler outside beforeShow
2. I don't think you can identify which `reason_submit2` link is clicked inside beforeShow

Alternatively, I defined 2 var's and a click handler for the link which will store the `name` and `form` and that will be used later in `fancyConfirm_ok`

**Complete code:**

```
$(function() {
    var r2sName = '', r2sForm = '';
    $(".reason_submit2").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        'modal': true
    }).click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        r2sName = $this.data("name");
        r2sForm = $this.data("form");        
    });

    jQuery(".fancyConfirm_ok").click(function() {
        $.fancybox.close();

        console.log('form : ' + r2sForm);
        console.log('name : ' + r2sName);
        console.log('message : ' + $("[name=reason2]").val());

        $($(".reason_submit2").data("form")).append($("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "reason").val($("#reason").val()));
        $($(".reason_submit2").data("form")).append($("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", $(".reason_submit2").data("name")));
        //document.forms[$(".reason_submit2").data("form")].submit();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/EvYvc/13/)

Other trick is to add a class to clicked link inside click handler and use that class to get the `name` and `form` inside `fancyConfirm_ok`, but personally I feel this is better.

Comment: This works fine, thank you! I just wonder why you wrapped it in a function, to get the variables local? It gives me an error though: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: that just `document.ready`, what version of jQuery are you using.. I think it was introduced in 1.7.. but yea defining a var inside a closure is better than global.

Comment: Aha, ok, yes I'm using 1.7.2 but I'm used to seeing/writing `$(document).ready(function() {` so I didn't think of that.

Comment: Regarding _2. I don't think you can identify which reason_submit2 link is clicked inside `beforeShow`_, you can always know what element was clicked using `beforeShow:function(){alert($(this.element).data("form"))}`

Answer (score 0):

I’m no expert in the FancyForm plugin. but I think you are binding the click event multiple times since you are binding it inside the `beforeShow` handler.

Try binding the click event on it’s own instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/h8sVY/

```
$(".reason_submit2").each(function() {
    $(this).fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        'modal': true
    });
});

$(".fancyConfirm_ok").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
    // etc...
});
​
```

Comment: It does solve the problem with the multiple callbacks, but it still only logs profile and never attribute...